# swapping letters next to each other in a string

Tags: c++, string, recursion, swap

Yesterday i did a code which swaps the letters that are next to each other in a string. For an example:

input="lalala", output="alalal". or input "bark", output = "arkb".
"b" is next to "a" and we swap. Now "b" is next to "r" and we swap again. And so on..

Today i tried doing it again, but without loops and in a "void(char* x)" function.
I'm really messed up and i'm trying to figure out how i can express the replacement in the function. I know it's something like :
temp=str1; str1=str2; str2=temp;

In the current code i can only reverse the string, but i have no idea how to use the "temp[1]" parameter... Some explanation would be of great help! :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void swapper(char* str){
char temp[1];
if(*str){
 swapper(str+1);
 cout << *str;}

 }

 int main (){

 char str[6] = "angel";
 cin >> str;
 char temp[1];
 swapper(str);
  }
```

Comment: I'm a bit unsure about your "swapping" ... aren't you just moving the first character to the end?

Comment: Are you really sure about the recursive `swapper()` call?

Comment: I'm not sure about it as well, but i'm really new to c++ and i got used only to "return values" using an int function or a string function.. Is it possible that i call another function inside this one and afterwards express the "swapping" using the recursion i've used above?

Comment: What goal are you trying to achieve? It seems that loops are the correct approach. If you want to do an all-recursive swapper, you probably would have to restrict input to strings whose lengths are power of two. Then you could recursively swap each half of the string until you got down to single characters.

Comment: You're not *swapping* anything, you're just printing characters. There's also no parameter named "temp" anywhere.

Comment: I did it with loops and it was fine, but recursion is really difficult for me and this was the second part of the exercise. 
I tried to make the function "void swapper(char* str, char* temp)" and then str=temp, get the "temp" in the recursive call, but it got really messy. 
@Logicrat I will try to do that. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to write a method that takes a C-style string and moves the first character to the last position, i.e. "abcde" -> "bcdea". A loop is the simplest approach here, but if you want to use recurrence, you need to write

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swapper(char* ptr)
{
    if(*(ptr + 1)) //if ptr points to the last character, the next one is '\0' and the recurrence should end
    {
        //swap currant character with the next
        char temp = *ptr;
        *ptr = *(ptr + 1);
        *(ptr + 1) = temp;
        //alternatively, you can use ptr[0] and ptr[1] instead of *ptr and *(ptr + 1), it's exactly the same thing

        //call swapper on the remainder of the string
        swapper(ptr + 1);
    }
}

int main ()
{
    char str[6] = "angel";
    swapper(str);
    cout << str;
}
```

Comment: //swap currant character with the next
             char temp = *ptr;
           *ptr = *(ptr + 1);
           *(ptr + 1) = temp;


I did the same when i was using a "for loop", but there i didn't use any pointers. I think that the "pointers and references" are also still difficult for me to understand and i must practice them more before moving to recursion. Thanks a lot for the help and the good explanation!! :)